# Centos 6.4 ignoring static ip address, getting dhcp address?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I have a Centos 6.4 server, which has been running at the same ip address for over a year. Today the server was rebooted, despite being setup to have a static ip, it used an ip from the dhcp server.

I have rebooted this machine before and this has never happened. The static ip address is setup as below:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

[image: cat ifcfg-eth0]

After restarting the network service, the ip address is 192.168.1.144 as expected. Upon additional reboots the ip address is lost. Is there something else I need to do here? Sort of strange to me...

Comment: Try to add a line with NM_CONTROLLED=no

Comment: your ifcfg-eth0 is maybe missing the UUID tag to identify the interface.
=> create one using 
# uuidgen eth0
then add UUID="...generated info..." in file.

Comment: `BOOTPROTO` command only accepts `none` , `bootp` or `dhcp` as values. The values 'static' means undefined and I believe it defaults to `dhcp`.